# Why reCAPTCHA integration fails?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, recaptcha-enterprise

It's a WordPress site. I am using Contact Form 7 with reCAPTCHA V2.

When I submit the form, it fails to submit.

Looking at the reCAPTCHA management screen, it says:

> We've detected that your site has a reCAPTCHA success rate of less than 50%. This may indicate a problem with your reCAPTCHA integration.

I have written this:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<action="?" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY KEY"></div>
<br>
```

I want the reCAPTCHA to succeed so the form can be submitted.

Comment: `<action="?" method="POST">` - is this intended to be a `form`?!

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Yes, It is officially written.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem.

Because it was a verification environment, it was the cause that the mail setting was not done.